# Actionable notification text overwrites in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, notifications, apple-push-notifications, actionable-notification

We have implemented Actionable Notification using Notification Extension Service. We receive push notifications and it shows the proper content for notification title, body, action buttons. We have defined 3 category say **onebtn**, **twobtn**, **threebtn** and all the unique actions for every category.

So, everything works fine for one notification but as we receive more than one notification in notification tray the **recent notification action button's text replace to all other notification's action button's text**. Ex. I have received notification for category **threebtn** then it will show me three buttons with three different texts say **Now, Later and Cancel**(These three button names will be the part of pay load received from push notification). Now I have received one more notification for category twobtn with button names, **Reply & Mark as read** and shown for that notification.

Now the issue is, it overwrites the button names of category twobtn to the notification which is received for threebtn notification. It means when I drag and open notification of category threebtn, its button names will be **Reply, Mark as paid & Cancel** *(third default text defined while assigning action)*. So every notification will have name Reply & Mark as Paid.

**Tried Solutions:**

- Set categories to plist as dictionary under NSNotification *(previously we added categories at runtime)*
- Assigned unique action and category name.

I am stuck with this issue since a week but not finding any proper solution. Kindly provide me some hint so I can fix this.

Thanks.

```
class NotificationService: UNNotificationServiceExtension {

    override func didReceive(_ request: UNNotificationRequest, withContentHandler contentHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationContent) -> Void) {

            let (pushNotificationBean, _) = saveNotificationAppGroupDefault(saveNotificationUserInfo: request.content.userInfo)

            registerNotificationCategory(pushNotificationBean: pushNotificationBean)

            self.contentHandler = contentHandler
            bestAttemptContent = (request.content.mutableCopy() as? UNMutableNotificationContent)

        }

            // MARK: - Register Notificaion Categories and Actions
            func registerNotificationCategory(pushNotificationBean: PushNotificationBean) {
                // Define Actions
                if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
                    // Define Action Yes

                    var singleBtnAction : UNNotificationAction

                    var trippleBtnYesAction : UNNotificationAction
                    var trippleBtnNoAction : UNNotificationAction
                    var trippleBtnPartialAction : UNNotificationAction

                    var doubleBtnYesAction : UNNotificationAction
                    var doubleBtNoAction : UNNotificationAction

                    // Positve Button Text
                    if let okActionText = pushNotificationBean.actionPositiveText, okActionText.count > 0{
                        // Single Button Action
                        singleBtnAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.OkAction,
                                                            title: okActionText,
                                                            options: .foreground)
                        // Double Button Action
                        doubleBtnYesAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.YesAction,
                                                                  title: okActionText,
                                                                  options: .foreground)
                        // Tripple Button Action
                        trippleBtnYesAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.YesAction,
                                                                   title: okActionText,
                                                                   options: .foreground)
                    }else{
                        // Single Button Action
                        singleBtnAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.OkAction,
                                                            title: self.OkAction,
                                                            options: .foreground)
                        // Double Button Action
                        doubleBtnYesAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.YesAction,
                                                                  title: self.YesAction,
                                                                  options: .foreground)
                        // Tripple Button Action
                        trippleBtnYesAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.YesAction,
                                                                   title: self.YesAction,
                                                                   options: .foreground)
                    }

                    // Negative Action Text
                    if let noActionText = pushNotificationBean.actionNegativeText, noActionText.count > 0{
                        // Double Button Action
                        doubleBtNoAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.NoAction,
                                                                title: noActionText,
                                                                options: .foreground)

                        // Tripple Button Action
                        trippleBtnNoAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.NoAction,
                                                                  title: noActionText,
                                                                  options: .foreground)
                    } else{
                        // Double Button Action
                        doubleBtNoAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.NoAction,
                                                                title: self.NoAction,
                                                                options: .foreground)
                        // Tripple Button Action
                        trippleBtnNoAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.NoAction,
                                                                  title: self.NoAction,
                                                                  options: .foreground)
                    }

                    // Partial Action Text
                    if let trippleBtnPartialActionText = pushNotificationBean.actionNeutralText, trippleBtnPartialActionText.count > 0{
                        // Tripple Button Action
                        trippleBtnPartialAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.PartialAction,
                                                                 title: trippleBtnPartialActionText,
                                                                 options: .foreground)
                    }else{
                        // Tripple Button Action
                        trippleBtnPartialAction = UNNotificationAction(identifier: self.PartialAction,
                                                                 title: self.PartialAction,
                                                                 options: .foreground)
                    }

                    // Define Single Category
                    let singleButtonCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: self.SingleButton,
                                                                      actions: [singleBtnAction],
                                                                      intentIdentifiers: [self.OkAction],
                                                                      options: [])

                    // Define Double Category
                    let doubleButtonCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: self.DoubleButton,
                                                                      actions: [doubleBtnYesAction,doubleBtNoAction],
                                                                      intentIdentifiers: [self.YesAction,self.NoAction],
                                                                      options: [])

                    // Define Tripple Category
                    let tripleButtonCategory = UNNotificationCategory(identifier: self.TripleButton,
                                                                      actions: [trippleBtnYesAction,trippleBtnNoAction,trippleBtnPartialAction],
                                                                      intentIdentifiers: [self.YesAction,self.NoAction,self.PartialAction],
                                                                      options: [])

                    UNUserNotificationCenter.current().setNotificationCategories([singleButtonCategory,doubleButtonCategory,tripleButtonCategory])
                }
            }
        }
```

[image: First Notification with three buttons]

[image: Second Notification with One Button]

[image: First Notification with three Buttons after receiving Second Notification]

Comment: Can you please share your code to handle button action,Notification Storyboard screen shot with Document outline as well as phone screen shot with  more then one notification?

Comment: @VDPurohit Please check the edit.

Comment: use elseif condition instead of if else.like if let postiveaction{} elseif let noaction{} else{}.

Comment: @Saurabh did you found any solution ?

Comment: If anyone found a solution to this, I would appreciate an answer!